# Increase the limit of file upload size in Heroku while uploading to Dropbox

Tags: php, heroku, file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have encountered an issue while uploading files to dropbox through my application that is hosted on Heroku. I wanted to upload approx 100MB files and they aren't being hosted on Heroku itself. I couldn't find anything on docs that'd address this issue entirely.

I tried an hack, I created a file named `custom_php.ini` and in `ProcFile` I added this line:

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -i custom_php.ini .`

And in my `custom_php.ini` file I set `upload_max_filesize` to `100M`.

But this didn't work for the files of size more than 10MB. What I'm missing here? Is it even possible? Is there any official way around?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To increase the file upload limit in Heroku while uploading to Dropbox, follow these steps:

1. Create a file named `custom_php.ini`, preferably.
2. Insert two attributes `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` and set their value to the desired upload limit. (In my case, its 100M)
3. Create a ProcFile and add this line `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -i custom_php.ini .`
4. Commit these changes to Heroku.

I missed to add `post_max_size` in my `custom_php.ini`. And by this method, you can override any `php.ini` configuration for Heroku.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually in the Heroku doc: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings

Just create a .user.ini file in the web directory with your custom directives

Answer (score 8):

I was going to comment on Romain's answer, but I don't have enough points:

The .user.ini file with the desired changes needs to be placed in the root folder, which is the /public folder if you're using Laravel.

Just check your root folder in your Procfile.

Answer (score 0):

In case of nginx and PHP FPM the following works:

Add these to nginx config (typically into `php-fpm.inc.conf`):

```
php_value[post_max_size]=100M
php_value[upload_max_filesize]=100M
```