# Post request with data more than 2MB gets error Heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, heroku

I have my PHP app running on heroku. The php app is running code igniter framework.
I have a third party partner who sends over files to a function that I allowed them to post data with.

Its a normal php function on codeigniter controller.

```
public function getting_third_party_data(){
// Fetching all information from the post request and saving to db
}
```

The problem is that whenever they send data below 2MB it works perfectly fine, but when its over 2MB my application sends an internal server error.

I contacted heroku people but they stopped replying for 2-3 weeks so I am asking here.

I added the `.user.ini` file with the following parameters

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

Even after this, whenever my app recieves data over 2MB it shows internal server error.

Comment: I know this thread is very old, but I just had the same problem and the `.user.ini` file solved it. For Masnad Hossain or the next ones, make sure it is in the document root (e.g. /public). See this Heroku official documentation's article : [Customizing Web Server and Runtime Settings for PHP - Setting the document root](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root])

Answer (score 1):

For those who tried `.user.ini` solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897926/7092969) and it did not work:

Our Laravel app is executed by Apache or Nginx. This can be changed via Heroku `Procfile` in the root directory:

1. Let's create `nginx.conf` in the root directory and add the following:

```
client_max_body_size 25M;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to index.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    # ensure that /index.php isn't accessible directly, but only through a rewrite
    internal;
}
```

2. Set `Procfile` content to:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/
```

3. Redeploy Heroku App
4. Cheers! :)