# Laravel Increase Upload file Size Heroku

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku, configuration

It looks like I cannot upload more than 2mb file with heroku.

I can upload 3mb file on my local but I can't upload the same file after pushing to heroku. (Using storage S3)

I updated the htaccess file and I have added

`ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');`

to my controller but it doesn't work.

Is there a way we can change the php.ini setting on heroku?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase the limit of file upload size in Heroku while uploading to Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897152/increase-the-limit-of-file-upload-size-in-heroku-while-uploading-to-dropbox)

Answer (score 2):

you need to create `.user.ini` file in root directory

```
post_max_size = 25M
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

then also updated `.Procfile` for apache

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -i user.ini rootDirectoryName/
```

for more information read this [blog](https://medium.com/@branick/custom-php-ini-w-laravel-on-heroku-f63ce3aae985) and [official documention](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings)

Comment: tried this and it seems to only work with a . before the user.ini

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, I was googling and trying many solutions, but nothing helped, so I've decided to switch from Apache to NGINX and the problem was solved - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509235/7092969

Overriding Heroku PHP ini files is kinda complicated and official Herkou documentation did not help me at all :/