# Multiple image upload to s3 using laravel on heroku malfunction

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to loop over a multiple input file select element

```
<label class="btn btn-success btn-md rounded-1" for="galleryFile">Create Album</label>
<input type="file" name="galleryFile[]" id="galleryFile" class="d-none" multiple accept="image/*">
```

and save all selected images to AWS s3

```
public function sendToCloud($file, $folder, $prefix) {
  $filePath = Auth::user()->userid . '/' .$folder.'/' . $prefix;

  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $filename  = $filePath . time() . '.' . $extension;

  Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, fopen($file, 'r+'), 'public');
  return Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
}

$unikPath = uniqid();
foreach ($request->file('galleryFile') as $key => $file) {
  if ($key == array_key_last($request->file('galleryFile'))) {
    $galleryUrl .= $this->sendToCloud($file, $unikPath . '/gallery', 'img_');
  } else {
    $galleryUrl .= $this->sendToCloud($file, $unikPath . '/gallery', 'img_') . ' | ';
  }
}
```

On my local machine it works very fine making me believe its not a problem with my code or laravel alone but when I deployed to heroku the upload behavior changed. What it does on heroku is

> if I selected 10 images to upload, it randomly picks and saves 2 of those images to s3 and return the s3 url of those 2 images 10 times.

I appreciate any help pointing in the right direction on how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check max upload file settings on php

Comment: On my local machine the upload works as expected but not on heroku. I just set the max upload file settings on heroku using [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897926/7895205) but it still didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Heeding the advice from @Peter O, I used `bin2hex(random_bytes(7))` to generate unique names for each file. This prevented the images from being overwritten by the next without the need for `sleep(1)`.

```
public function sendToCloud($file, $folder, $prefix) {
  $filePath = Auth::user()->userid . '/' .$folder.'/' . $prefix;

  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $filename  = $filePath . bin2hex(random_bytes(7)) . '.' . $extension;

  Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, fopen($file, 'r+'), 'public');
  return Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
}
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

So I was able to fix this. After multiple trials, I realized that all the images were actually being processed and sent to s3 but I could only see two because the speed of processing was making the images overwrite the previous ones with the same name.

> **How?**

The PHP `uniqid()`  [function generates a unique ID based on the microtime](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp), three images could process at the same time which means they'll all have the same value based of the uniqid() function.

> **How I solved it**

I added a sleep function to the `foreach` loop to delay execution by 1 second allowing the program time to generate a new unique name.

```
foreach ($request->file('galleryFile') as $key => $file) {
  if ($key == array_key_last($request->file('galleryFile'))) {
    $galleryUrl .= $this->sendToCloud($file, $unikPath . '/gallery', 'img_');
  } else {
    $galleryUrl .= $this->sendToCloud($file, $unikPath . '/gallery', 'img_') . ' | ';
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps someone someday.

Comment: A better solution is to (1) generate random file names using `random_bytes` rather than `uniqid`, and (2) check whether you have opened an existing file with `fopen($file, ...)`, and if so, generate a different file name to avoid overwriting the existing one.

Comment: Also, the solution you give here is fragile -- it assumes the system time will never be changed while your application is running, which may not always be the case for many reasons, including server clock synchronization. See also the documentation for [uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Comment: "I added a sleep function to the foreach loop to delay execution by 1 second allowing the program time to generate a new unique name." What happens if a second user uploads something 1 second after the first user?

Comment: @ceejayoz, @Peter O.
From my `sendToCloud()` function, you'll notice that every user has a `userid` which is unique to each user. When uploading, each upload is sent to a folder created by the userid of the user uploading the item. #2 `uniqid()` is only used to create an inner folder for each user against future uploads. #3 I added `sleep()` because I used `time()` to create file name. Delaying execution by 1 sec will allow the system to create another name with 1 sec interval between that name and the previous name. Final path is usual like `s3Url/userid/uniqid/filename`

Answer (score 1):

At the time I posted this answer, you had written an answer explaining your solution.  However, a better solution is to—

1. generate random file names using `random_bytes` (together with `bin2hex`) rather than `uniqid`, and
2. check whether you have opened an existing file with `fopen($file, ...)`, and if so, generate a different file name to avoid overwriting the existing one.

Also, the solution you give in your answer is fragile -- it assumes the system time will never be changed while your application is running, which may not always be the case for many reasons, including server clock synchronization. See also the documentation for [`uniqid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Comment: Use `bin2hex(random_bytes(16))`, for example, to get a readable string.

Comment: `bin2hex(random_bytes(16))` returned a much better string than just `random_bytes(16)`. After editing my code to bin2hex(random_bytes(7)), it worked as expected both on localhost and on heroku. Once again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Every user has a `userid` which is unique to each user; when uploading, each upload is sent to a folder created by the userid of the user uploading the item. #2 `uniqid()` is only used to create an inner folder for each user against future uploads. #3 I added `sleep()` because I used `time()` to create file name. Delaying execution by 1 sec will allow the system to create another name with 1 sec interval between that name and the previous name. Final path is usual like `s3Url/userid/uniqid/filename`. I'll use `bin2hex(random_bytes(7))` in place of `time()` without `sleep()`.