# Updating image with random unique name and upload path with database is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and i want to update image with random unique name, upload path with database but not working

I want to update image with codeigniter but not working fine. i am sharing code model.
tabel name dpr_user and field name user_pic,

**form view**

form view page is working fine here is code i am using model form

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>update_picture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Change Profile Picture</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Upload New Profile Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" size = "20" class="form-control"/> 
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" id="picture_id" class="form-control">

    <div class="modal-footer">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
   </form>
```

**Model**

```
function update_picture()  
    {  

        $db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE);

         if(isset($_FILES["image_file"]["name"]))  
         {  
              $config['upload_path'] = './upload/userimage/';  
              $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';  
              $this->load->library('upload', $config);  
              if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))  
              {  
                  $error =  $this->upload->display_errors(); 
                  echo json_encode(array('msg' => $error, 'success' => false));
              }  
              else 
              {  
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $userpic = $data['name'];
                    $db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE);
                    $id = $this->input->post('picture_id');
                    $today_date = date('d-m-Y');

                    $update =$db2->query('UPDATE dpr_user SET user_pic="'.$userpic.'" ,updated="'.$today_date.'" WHERE id = "'.$id.'"');
                    return $update;

              }  
         }  
    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection ! Use [Query builder](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines

```
$extension = pathinfo($FILES["image_file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // <<this
$config['upload_path'] = './upload/userimage/';  
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';  
$config['file_name'] = rand(100,10000).time().".".$extension; //<<and this
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Reference : [File Uploading class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#id7)

Comment: A better approach for generating a random file name is `random_bytes` (together with `bin2hex`), rather than `rand(100,10000).time()` which is not a cryptographic RNG.  A more robust approach would be to check whether the upload succeeded to avoid overwriting existing files.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702170/multiple-image-upload-to-s3-using-laravel-on-heroku-malfunction)