# Error user uploading file on Heroku but not local

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have an app where the user can upload a picture file.  I use s3 for storage. On my local machine this works fine but when I deploy to Heroku, every time I try to upload (by clicking a form button in my app) I get an error saying 'The "" file does not exist or is not readable'. It crashes on this line of code:

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/profile', request('image'));
```

The problem seems to lie with the put method inputs. I did a dump and die on request('image') right before that line of code. On my local copy here's what I see:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1236 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "gary-bendig-6GMq7AGxNbE-unsplash.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "phpD90.tmp"
  basename: "phpD90.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD90.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD90.tmp"
  aTime: 2020-06-30 20:09:05
  mTime: 2020-06-30 20:09:05
  cTime: 2020-06-30 20:09:05
  inode: 5629499534269665
  size: 2328835
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD90.tmp"
}
```

Here's what I see on Heroku:

```
^ Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1168 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "gary-bendig-6GMq7AGxNbE-unsplash.jpg"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/app/public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

I'm guessing it's some kind of file system permission problem but open to ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that uploading pics <2MB worked. Maybe it's a setting in php.ini but not sure how to edit that on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (.user.ini) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897926/7092969.

If it did not work:

1. Let's create `nginx.conf` in the root directory and add the following:

```
client_max_body_size 25M;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to index.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    # ensure that /index.php isn't accessible directly, but only through a rewrite
    internal;
}
```

2. Set `Procfile` content to:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/
```

3. Redeploy Heroku App