# How to solve a long time to upload file in heroku?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, deep-learning, streamlit

I have deployed my deep learning model streamlit app in Heroku.
My heroku app is taking a long time to upload `.csv` file from my local(file size is 700mb)
and then it times out.

Can any one suggest suitable answer?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897152/increase-the-limit-of-file-upload-size-in-heroku-while-uploading-to-dropbox

Comment: You could get away with pushing to github and setting up heroku CI

Comment: can you add the code for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Cloud or Git LFS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).