# How to deploy php.ini changes to Heroku?

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a Laravel app. Initially in my local server, I made few changes in `php.ini` like

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 260M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 260M
```

Now I want these changes to be applied to my website which I have deployed on Heroku. Will I be needed to deploy `php.ini` too? Or will the changes be automatically updated? Or do I need to write all those changes in `.htaccess` and then deploy it?

Comment: first link by google "heroku php.ini".. why u don't try to google this? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#user-ini-files-recommended

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you answered your own question there, you made those changes locally. So, unless you replicate the settings on the webserver that will run your application they aren't going to be in effect...

[Edit 1] I'll see what I can find about changing this settings within Heroku

[Edit 2] Here you go, see the Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings OR another thread which has detailed step by step instructions. [Increase the limit of file upload size in Heroku while uploading to Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897152/increase-the-limit-of-file-upload-size-in-heroku-while-uploading-to-dropbox)

Comment: A question sir. I know that one free acount from heroku, it don't permit you upload files.. the next questions is.. how I upload files to heroku.. using a hosting plan? prices are bigger.