# Heroku set upload_max_filesize for Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, file-upload

I run a laravel application on Heroku using hobby dynos.
I followed the steps on setting the additional php.ini settings from their help center [Link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#how-applications-are-launched-during-dyno-boot), all to no avail.
I used an apache server and Nginx, following all the rules I could find on the internet. I also used the `ini_set()` function inline in my application all to no avail.
I know I'm not the only one with a laravel app on Heroku that needs to change php.ini settings, please help me with advice if you've done this before.

Comment: Did you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897152/increase-the-limit-of-file-upload-size-in-heroku-while-uploading-to-dropbox

Comment: Yes, I did. I set .user.ini and also custom_php.ini.