# Getting error "Payload too large" with dokku

Tags: laravel, dokku

I have a Laravel application hosted on a Linux server using dokku. (dokku feeds from heroku buildpack).

Now I have a challenge uploading files that are large. files up to 300 MB. I keep getting the error "Payload too large" I have done all I know to do at the nginx level by increasing client_max_body_size and the rest. however, the error persists.

I need solutions on how to go about resolving the issue of increasing upload size with dokku.

Comment: [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897152/increase-the-limit-of-file-upload-size-in-heroku-while-uploading-to-dropbox)?